# How do I get the PackageID for Azure Devops API?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-artifacts

I need the list of available versions for a Universal Package stored in Azure Devops. My thought is to call the REST API Get Package Versions to get a list of the versions for packages on a feed.

```
GET https://feeds.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/packaging/Feeds/{feedId}/Packages/{packageId}/versions?api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

The problem is that it requires a packageId, which is the GUID and I only know the name. The only way I've figured out so far to convert a package name to a GUID is using "Get Packages" but that returns every package on the feed (which for me includes thousands of NPM packages) and that makes the download very large for the handful of items I need. Is there some way to extract the packageId for a given package name? Or is there a better way to extract all the versions for a package?

Comment: this api as well as many other devops-apis support the idOrName-concept so you can use either the id or the name. so in short: try using the name. this doc (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifactspackagetypes/universal/get%20package%20version?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) even uses the name as placeholder

Comment: Unfortunately the Get Version API is to "Show information about a package version," not get the list of versions. I agree that it's strange that some of the APIs take the name while others, like Get Package Versions requires "Id of the package (GUID Id, not name)."

Answer (score 3):

Someone pointed out to me that the Get Packages API has options for `IncludeAllVersions` and `packageNameQuery` to achieve what I want rather than using `GetAllVersions`.

```
https://feeds.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/packaging/Feeds/{feedId}/Packages?includeAllVersions=true&packageNameQuery={packageName}&protocol​Type=nuget
```

Comment: Forgive my mislead above and miss this API. Glad you could find correct API and let you avoid another trouble. You can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) thus other SO users will be able to refer to this work solution:-)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have checked some docs and found there's no direct API can let you get specified packaged ID, right? Also, as the doc [said](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifacts/artifact%20%20details/get%20package?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#uri-parameters), the package name could not be used in this API:

[image]

---

In fact, you have very close to the answer. Just add some **filter** while you running `Get Packages`. But this need you execute some script in Powershell command line or Powershell ISE which is the most convenient approach can for you use. You can also run below script in Azure Devops pipeline, but compare with running in command line, it is a bit cumbersome.

Run below script in your **Powershell command line** or **Powershell ISE**:

```
$token = "{your PAT token}"
$url = 'https://feeds.dev.azure.com/{org name}/_apis/packaging/Feeds/{feed ID}/packages'

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get

$results = $response.value | Where {$_.name -eq "{Package Name}"} #|

Write-Host "results = $($results | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"
```

**Note:** In the above script, you just need to replace the value of `PAT token`, `Organization name` and your `package name`.

---

Then you will get the info of the specified package, and you can copy the package ID from the command line and apply it in another place :

[image]

**Note:** The above script can also be applied in the Powershell task of Azure Devops without change anything.

Comment: Thank you for the script. I'm not a powershell expert, but this looks like it is pulling the entire list of packages from the server and filtering it locally. If so, that is what I am doing already, but the problem remains that it takes too long to send the entire list and parse the json. I need it to work faster so I was hoping that I missed an API or technique to get the ID for fewer than all packages and have the filtering done on the server.

Comment: @Chuckkir Sorry to say, the azure devops does not provide and support filter on server until now. This script does not return the entire result firstly since you said that you have nearly thousands packages. Look at the fifth line of my script, it just return the specific one which you want by using the filter in the script. This could help for reduce the return time.

Comment: Thanks. Filtering the list isn't a problem; rather it takes way too long to do the download and json parsing before getting to the filtering. It's unfortunate that there is no way to get the GUID other than getting them all, but thank you for clarifying the situation.

Comment: @Chuckkir Download and json parsing? Do you mean done this manually or done by the script(command line)? Also, here you must use GUID instead of name is because we allow the same package name exists in feed just require you specified the different version. That’s why this API you must using GUID.

Comment: Downloading the list of all packages; the REST call you make in line 4. That brings down a lot of data. Then I extract the GUID and make a REST call to Get Package Versions. It's all in a script.

Comment: Since I'm making the call to Get Package Versions, it doesn't matter how many versions there are with the same name? However, I suppose there could be different package types with the same name? In that case it could return them all and I'd be happy to pick the right type.

Comment: @Chuckkir yeah, correct about what you supposed. Since several report tickets received recently, I think it would be more convenient that we could consider take this into our roadmap if this feature is expected and urgent by many users. Hope you can raise a suggest ticket on our [official forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21). Thus our team PM can reviewed it then consider to take in develop.

Comment: where do you get the value for feedid?